# ListView not displaying in Navigation Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I'm trying to display a ListView from an ArrayList of strings in my Navigation Menu and its just coming up blank, no data is being passed to the ListView.

To access a new layout file other than activity_main.xml, I'm using "ConstraintLayout layout1 = (ConstraintLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.nav_choose_foods, null);" then, "ListView listView =  layout1.findViewById(R.id.search_list);"

This at least doesn't crash the program, it seems to find the ID ok, but it's still not displaying the ListView. I this possible? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying here?

Thanks for any help!

Code is below:

Main Actvity -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter_AllFoods.ItemClickListener, RecyclerViewAdapter_Nutrients.ItemClickListener, RecyclerViewAdapter_FoodTotals.ItemClickListener{

    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar);

        ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);
        ConstraintLayout layout1 = (ConstraintLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.nav_choose_foods, null);
        // pass the Open and Close toggle for the drawer layout listener
        // to toggle the button
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // to make the Navigation drawer icon always appear on the action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Apple");
        list.add("Banana");
        list.add("Pineapple");


        adapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

        ListView listView =  layout1.findViewById(R.id.search_list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapterList);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {


            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--the root view must be the DrawerLayout-->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"

        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_choose_foods.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/search_list"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="254dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    >
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:title="Choose Foods">
            <menu>
                <group
                    android:id="@+id/menu_top"
                    android:checkableBehavior="single">

                    <item
                        app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_choose_foods"
                        android:id="@+id/nav_radios"
                        android:title=""
                        />

                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
        <item
            android:title="Activity Level">
            <menu>
                <group
                    android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
                    android:checkableBehavior="single">

                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if this helps anyone, I gave up on using "navigation_menu.xml" file. Instead I just used an include layout in my activity_main.xml file under "com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView". No need to inflate or anything, the id gets found no problem. Not sure if this is the best way to go, but it works.

If anyone has a better solution for this let me know.